# Sonar Alert : Refactor this method to not always return the same value

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using this code to initialize an action handler and I'm getting a Sonar Alert with a severity blocker:

> Refactor this method to not always return the same value

for the following code:

```
private static boolean initialized = false;
public static boolean initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        //TODO
        initialized = true ;
        return initialized ;
    }
    // TODO
    return initialized;
}
```

How can I improve this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what is hidden under the `// TODO` it is impossible to propose something useful. The following code:

```
public static boolean initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        // TODO
        initialized = true;
        return initialized;
    }
    // TODO
    return initialized;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public static boolean initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = true;
        return initialized;
    }
    return initialized;
}
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
public static boolean initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The returned boolean value is always the same, so there is no sense to return it. The final code:

```
public static void initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = true;
    }
}
```